# Getting duplicate records in DB using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have an ASP.Net MVC site that is behaving strangely. Almost duplicate records are being created. The only field that is different in the records is the Key/Id field. There is a datetime field that is exactly the same in both records. To complicate the matter it only happens once or twice for every couple of hundred records created. Since the StartTime in the duplicate records is identical I assume it must be happening somewhere between the  context Add and the context SaveChanges calls. I'm using EntityFramework 6.1.3

```
  [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult LogTime(CheckinVM checkin)
    {
     var employee = db.Employees.FirstOrDefault(e => e.CompanyId.Equals(checkin.EmployeeId));           
     var dept = db.Departments.Find(checkin.DepartmentId);
     var currentWage = db.Wages.Where(w => w.Department.Id.Equals(checkin.DepartmentId))
        .Where(w => w.Employee.CompanyId.Equals(checkin.EmployeeId))
        .Where(w => w.EffectiveDateTime < DateTime.Now)
        .OrderByDescending(w => w.EffectiveDateTime)
        .ThenByDescending(w => w.Id).Select(w => w.Amount)
        .FirstOrDefault();

     var tc = new TimeCard
            {
            StartTime = DateTime.Now,
            EnteredBy = User.Identity.Name,
            LastEdit = DateTime.Now,
            LastEditedBy = "Timecard UI",
            Department = dept,
            Employee = employee,
            Wage = currentWage
            };
     db.TimeCards.Add(tc);
     db.SaveChanges();
     return Json(test, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

This is being posted via the Jquery ajax call

```
$('.campaign').click(function () {
     var id = this.id;
     $('#'+id).prop("disabled", true);
     var employeeId = $('#EmployeeId').val();
     var dept = $('#' + id).data("dept");
     var checkin = {
               EmployeeId: employeeId,
               DepartmentId: dept
              };
    $.ajax({
          url: "@Url.Action("LogTime","Home")",
          type: "POST",
          contentType: "application/json",
          data: JSON.stringify({ Checkin: checkin })
          })
          .done(function (data) {$('#'+id).prop("disabled", false);});
     });
```

The Timecard class and table are created via the code first process against a SQL 2012 DB.

```
 [Table("TimeCards", Schema = "TCT")]
public class TimeCard
{
    [Display(Name = "Timecard Id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Start Time")]
    [DisplayFormat(NullDisplayText = "N/A")]
    public DateTime? StartTime { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "End Time")]
    [DisplayFormat(NullDisplayText = "Open")]
    public DateTime? EndTime { get; set; }

    public virtual Department Department { get; set; }

    public virtual Employee Employee { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
    public float? Wage { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Entered By")]
    public string EnteredBy { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Last Edited")]
    [DisplayFormat(NullDisplayText = "N/A")]
    public DateTime? LastEdit { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Last Edited By")]
    [DisplayFormat(NullDisplayText = "N/A")]
    public string LastEditedBy { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Deleted")]
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = @"{0:hh\:mm}")]
    public TimeSpan? Hours
    {
        get
        {
            var t = EndTime - StartTime;
            return t;
        }
        private set { }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you hitting the `LogTime` method 2 times ? Can you put a breakpoint and confirm ?

Comment: Are you calling your ajax via a button click or some kind of user action?  Remember that a user 'can' click a button multiple times before a page changes.  without proper checks on your requests, this could easily cause duplicate records.

Comment: If I were hitting the LogTime method twice the times would not be exactly the same, down to the millisecond. I've tried doing multiple clicks as fast as possible and each time the record is different by at least several milliseconds.

Comment: What's happening to the Ajax return; you're returning a JSON value but not handling it? Add a trace to the SQL server; you'll see the SQL generated by EF without affecting the call.

Comment: Try wrapping them in a lock or do using(db)?

Comment: I've  added $(id).prop("disabled", true); to the function before making the ajax call and then added $(id).prop("disabled", false); in the "done" section of the ajax call to see if that makes a difference.

Answer (score -1):

This has happened me before. I'm going out on a limb and guessing that the first record is reading from the table *into* the Entity Framework change tracking cache, and the second record is being read straight from the cache then.

Solution:

- Add the [`AsNoTracking()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679352(v=vs.103).aspx) clause to your queries, to prevent them from being read into the cache, see this [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh394143.aspx) by Julie Lerman for more info.

Other possible tips and tricks:

- Disable the button that is calling the method after click, using jQuery
- Use locking in Entity Framework, or set the transaction isolation level of the database, to something like serializable as a temporary step in finding out whether EF is actually even going to the database the second time - you'll see an error 1205 indicating deadlocking if you successfully replicate it.
- Have the html button that is calling the method also send in a GUID or randomly generated string, and you will see if it's definitely the HTML request being called twice - i.e. before you jquery serialize it, update some random field with a new GUID.

Comment: There is no reading of records first. The app simply creates new records. 
I've Disabled the button as you suggested, but I am still getting random dups.